# Prevent re-render after state change with BottomTabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Everytime I press a button that changes state stored in context of both screens linked with a bottomtabnavigator a gets logged twice. The same happens when I use a stack navigator where if I press tha button in the screen I navigated to, a gets logged twice, as if both screens re rendered even if only one of them is visible.
How do I prevent this from happening, only allowing the actually visible screen to get re-rendered?

App.js:

```
const navigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Index: IndexScreen,
    Test: tester
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Index', 
  }
);

const App = createAppContainer(navigator);

export default () => {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

IndexScreen.js:

```
const IndexScreen = () => {
  const { state, ..., increment } = useContext(Context); //... represents some other methods here
  console.log("a");
... //a button that just increments a number stored in state
}
```

tester.js has a structure analog to the structure of IndexScreen.js.

Comment: why does it matter they re-render? is there a side-effect?

Comment: It may reduce performance.

Comment: This sounds like a case of premature optimization to me.